# Set global proxy in Android

Tags: proxy

In order to provide safe browsing, I want to set global proxy to route all http/https requests from any browser to my proxy server on both WiFi and 2G/3G networks for non rooted Android devices with OS version 2.2 and above.

After categorization, proxy server will send response to browsers.

I have seen so many posts in SO also, but nobody has explained for Mobile networks(2G/3G).
Please inform whether there is a possibility or not at all? If yes, please suggest a way.
If anybody have idea, please share your thoughts.Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Gopi.

Comment: Newer Android versions let proxy be configured fro individual APNs or a global proxy which works for all networks including Wi-Fi and Mobile data. But proxy server can't handle ***all traffic*** in true sense. Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217801/218526

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several [proxy apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=109) available to accomplish something like that. Though most of them require root access to the device, not all do (I have not tested any of them, so I cannot tell in detail).

However, a different approach might be checking into [VPN apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=115), as that's pretty much what you targeting: a [Virtual Private Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vpn), where your server acts as a "checkpoint". Many of those VPN apps do not require root access, but many also use a dedicated VPN provider. Still, the linked lists should contain a working solution for you.

<sup>Disclosure: the linked lists are maintained by me, to provide you good "jump-points".</sup>

Comment: Yes Izzy, I too saw many apps and tested some of them, but no one is supporting proxy under 2G/3G, all are supporting for WiFi only for non rooted device. For rooted there are many working apps.                                        And Yes, If this setting global proxy approach doesn't fulfill my requirement then I need to go back to VPN approach. Anyway thanks for your time and suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure for any "pure proxy app" to work with 2G/3G, but I know several (if not all) of the VPN solutions do. That's why I've mentioned them as "fall-back". Besides, as to the question's description, that even might be the recommended solution ;)

Comment: Now I will look for VPN apps which suit for my requirement.Thanks for your time and valuable information.

Comment: Good luck! Hope my above link can serve as a good starter.